# Do users resize text?

Tags: usability

I'm redesigning a website. For certain content areas the layout is fine at my text size but screws up if I set the text any bigger. I often resize pages with Firefox, but the whole page resizes so the layout still works.

So, should I worry about users having larger text but the same CSS otherwise? I don't know how to test for this sort of thing. The site works fine with every browser I've looked at it with. I know some usability devices change layouts but don't they ignore normal styles altogether?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it really depends on the target audience i'd say. if its a frontfacing website i think you should cover your bets and try and make it look good (or atleast usable) with increased text size, if its an internal website perhaps it doesnt matter so much..

sorry for the vague awnser, but its really something the customer (internal or external) can awnser best

Comment: It is front facing and I defiantly want to play it safe. So your saying (some) people do resize text while keeping the rest of the design the same size? This is not the default behavior of firefox:  http://www.labnol.org/software/browsers/resize-text-in-firefox-3-without-changing-the-size-of-images/2775/

Comment: in IE you can choose to set the text size (separate from page zoom), im not sure what the deal is with diffrent DPI settings in windows but i'd definitly try setting a diffrent dpi and see how it looks

Comment: DPI settings in windows 7 dont appear to effect webpages. thanks